# Call documentReady function on window load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A quick one...

How can I run a function at window load defined in document ready?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //How do I run this, down from Load??
   function thisFunction() {
      alert("This function");
   }
});

$(window).load(function() {
   thisFunction();
});
```

Comment: Why not define it outside of the document.ready?

Comment: It's a script that resizes some images. It doesn't work when defined outside ready.

Comment: @Kenneth: That's not possible. You can declare the function wherever you like, as long as you call it after the document is ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //How do I run this, down from Load??
   function thisFunction() {
      alert("This function");
   }
   $(window).load(thisFunction);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //How do I run this, down from Load??
   window.thisFunction = function() {
      alert("This function");
   }
});

$(window).load(function() {
   thisFunction();
});
```

This will work.